# gitlab redirects push/fetch/clone to sign in

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch, git-clone

I am trying to push a branch into a gitlab remote repository and an example of the behaviour would be:

```
git clone http://(path to branch)
Cloning into 'origin'...
fatal: unable to update url base from redirection:
    asked for: http://(path to branch)/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
redirect: http://(path to root)/users/sign_in
```

please note the changes on the urls and also I entered my credentials in .git/config, as presented below

```
[user]
    name = myname
    pwd = mypassword
    password = mypassword
```

It's probably relevant that when I signed up, the repository asked for a public key that I had to make exclusively for the project.

Answer (score 7):

Try cloning the repository with no path to branch first, then checkout to the branch you want.

`git clone git@(domain and path to the repository)`

See details [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/command-line-commands.html). I'd recommend just [setting up SSH access](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-your-ssh-keys.html) only takes a few minutes and much easier once it's running.

Next, just cd into the project you made and run

`git branch -a`

to view all project branches. Finally

`git checkout [branchname]`

should switch you to the branch.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need add SSH key to your profile.

Steps to add SSH key:

- Generate ssh key `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "tdeshmukh@example.com"`
- Copy that generated key - `cat C:\Users\tejashreed/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub | clip`
  If above command fails then directly copy ssh key by `clip < C:\Users\tejashreed/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub`
- Add your public SSH key to your GitLab account by:

Clicking your avatar in the upper right corner and selecting Settings.
Navigating to SSH Keys and pasting your public key in the Key field. If you:

Created the key with a comment, this will appear in the Title field.
Created the key without a comment, give your key an identifiable title like Work Laptop or Home Workstation.

Click the Add key button.

Answer (score 0):

Issue for me was the origin url was non existent to trying to push redirected to login page

Comment: Good point. Don't assume the path scheme. Copy it from the "Clone" menu.